# Set default timeout in all asynchronous requests

Tags: asynchronous, jax-rs, resteasy

I'm using `@Suspended AsyncResponse response` in my requests and starting threads to process the request. When the process finishes, I'm trying to resume the response but RestEasy is marking the request as done because the request thread has finished and no timeout was set in the response. If I set timeout, it works fine but I would need to set the timeout in every asynchronous request I want want to implement. Is there anyway to horizontally set the timeout to all my suspended AsyncRequests?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the [JAX-RS 2.0 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-fr-eval-spec/jsr339-jaxrs-2.0-final-spec.pdf?), the [RESTEasy documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.13.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#Asynchronous_HTTP_Request_Processing) and the [Jersey documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/async.html#d0e10196) don't mention anything about setting a default timeout for the [`AsyncResponse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/AsyncResponse.html).

The [Jersey documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/async.html#d0e10196) mentions the following:

> By default, there is no timeout defined on the suspended [`AsyncResponse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/AsyncResponse.html) instance. A custom timeout and timeout event handler may be defined using [`setTimeoutHandler(TimeoutHandler)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/AsyncResponse.html#setTimeoutHandler-javax.ws.rs.container.TimeoutHandler-) and [`setTimeout(long, TimeUnit)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/AsyncResponse.html#setTimeout-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) methods. The [`setTimeoutHandler(TimeoutHandler)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/AsyncResponse.html#setTimeoutHandler-javax.ws.rs.container.TimeoutHandler-) method defines the handler that will be invoked when timeout is reached. The handler resumes the response with the response code `503` (from [`Response.Status.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.Status.html#SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE)). A timeout interval can be also defined without specifying a custom timeout handler (using just the [`setTimeout(long, TimeUnit)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/AsyncResponse.html#setTimeout-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) method).

So, the solution won't be different from the solution you are already using:

```java
@GET
public void longRunningOperation(@Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {

    // Register a timeout handler
    asyncResponse.setTimeoutHandler(new TimeoutHandler() {

        @Override
        public void handleTimeout(AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {
            asyncResponse.resume(Response.status(SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE)
                .entity("Operation timed out. Please try again.").build());
        }
    });

    // Set timeout
    asyncResponse.setTimeout(15, SECONDS);

    // Execute long running operation in new thread
    executor.execute(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            executeLongRunningOp();
            asyncResponse.resume("Hello async world!");
        } 
    });
}
```